# Use hardware acceleration without wmode=direct?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way to use hardware acceleration in flash without changing the `wmode` property to 'direct? Or, in other words, is there some way I can use hardware acceleration and still have html elements in front of the swf? I would really love to layer an html ui on top of a swf flv player, but it seems I can't use hardware acceleration with such a setup.

Comment: Hardware acceleration enables a separate rendering pipeline for content, which is why it is on "top". If you want to add an overlay for your video, you will have to build it within your video player.

Comment: I have suspicions that this is possible because we are currently using an osmf player that appears to use hardware acceleration, or at least it looks really good, and its using wmode=opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good write up about the different WMODE settings and what they do/do not allow for.

http://labs.almerblank.com/2011/03/the-wmode-embed-parameter-de-mystified/

But wait...

I also found an article on the Adobe site that seems to indicate that some browsers do actually allow for layering of "direct" content within HTML. The support for layering is not across the board based on this. But it looks like the browser list is a little out of date.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_